# How do I give my worker.js access to the `sails` object

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Following Heroku's encouragement to a [worker dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing) I created a worker.js file in my Sails project. However, this file is executed independently with a `node worker.js` but i'd like to reuse the config I set up for my sails app. Specifically the `sails.log` and sails' models.

How do I give my independently executed `worker.js` file access to the `sails` object.

Comment: @TomSel could you please answer this question. I know you implemented something similar in March through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29054652/using-node-cluster-module-with-sailsjs-eaddrinuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tons of tweeting and asking around, I finally managed this with `sails.load()`. Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24124301/3970701):

```
var Sails = require('sails');
Sails.load(function(err, sails) {
   // At this point you have access to all your models, services, etc.
   sails.log('Worker is ready');
   fireJobListener();
});
```